# Why does console program print directory list rather than command line arguments?

Tags: c, linux

I am doing exercise question 5-10 in K&R (The C Programming Language), and I am unable to understand behavior of this simple C code.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ctr = 1;
    if(argc == 1)
        printf("Usage: Reverse polish notation evaluator\n");
    else {
        printf("Total count : %d\n", argc);
        while(argc-- > 1)
            printf("%s\n", argv[ctr++]);
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

This code is working fine for all arguments except the " * " (without quotes) character. When " * " is given as argument, the code prints name of all the files present in that directory. Is it default behavior or has something to do with meta characters or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: the concept call filename expansion

Comment: try this code as command to observe the `*` effect `for i in *;do echo $i;done;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has something to do with your *shell*. Your shell expands the `*` character into a space-separated list of files in your current working directory.

Comment: Would it hurt to mention that adding quotation marks or a backlash on before the `*` on the command line would fix it? :)

Comment: I edited the answer to add this info and some more explanation, but I guess my edit was not accepted

Comment: @R..: Well, that depends on the shell, doesn't it? That's true in Bash and Windows `cmd`, I suppose. But I couldn't speak to tksh, fish or ksh...

Comment: @blue: Generally editing other people's answers should be reserved for correcting typos, formatting, or cases like where they accidentally said the opposite of what they meant (and it's clear from the context that this is what happened). If you have additional information to add, it's better to write your own answer or include the additional info in a comment on the answer and let the person who answered incorporate it themselves if they feel it's appropriate.